# R packages reinstallation on a new system not working

Tags: r

i changed to a new laptop and i am trying to install all old packages from the former laptop but its given me an error message:

Error in install.packages : invalid subscript type 'list'

I have tried to use the unlist function but its not working

```
installedpreviously <- read.csv('installed_previously.csv')
    baseR<- as.data.frame(installed.packages())
        toInstall <- setdiff(installedpreviously , baseR)
            install.packages(toInstall)
```

it should automatically load and install the packages

Answer (score 1):

You need an atomic vector of the package names, not a data frame. So just use the `$` operator to get the vector of package names from your data frame and it should work